# How Classloader determines which classes it can load?

Tags: java, classloader

I'm reading on class loading in Java.

### Motivation

Assuming we have a classloader hierarchy that looks like this, I understand that classes loaded by `First` are not directly accessible by classes loaded by `Second` (and vice versa).

```
 Bootstrap
     |
   System
     |
   Common
   /    \
First Second
```

I also understand that a classloader checks with its parent class loader whether it can load the class and, if that is the case, delegates the loading to its parent.

### Question

How do classloaders actually determine whether they can load some given class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That differs depending on the implementation of the classloader. But all Classes a ClassLoader can load are retrieved by [ClassLoader.findClass(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#findClass%28java.lang.String%29)

There are many implementations but the most common one is the [URLClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) which loads classes from directories and jar files.

Answer (score 0):

The classloader checks all classes *(java class files)* within your [`CLASSPATH`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29) path variable. If your class is found there, it exists, otherwise it doesn't.

So practically, **your `/src` directory and all subdirectories (=packages) are scanned.**

Answer (score 0):

The classloader transforms the requested class name into a file name and then tries to find a "class file" of that name from a file system.  As @poitroae notes, it uses the CLASSPATH variable, if set, as a starting place.  Most IDEs and such extend this to include your working directories for the project.